# How to deal with missing values in degree function in R?

Tags: r, igraph

I'm currently using degree function in igraph. But the problem is my data set has lots of missing values. So if I use degree function, degree centrality is strongly biased. And my data set consists of several groups, it might be also biased due to the size of groups. This is the syntax I'm using right now.

```
graph <- graph.adjacency(A, mode='directed', diag = FALSE)
indgree <- degree(graph, v = V(graph), mode = c("in"),
   loops = TRUE, normalized = TRUE)
```

So, my question will be:
1) Is there any way to deal with missing values in this function?
2) Can I calculate indegree centrality based on the size of each group?